# Sublime Text 2 and ZF2 ... auto complete not works

Tags: ide, zend-framework2, sublimetext2

I installed sublime text 2 with all php dependencies.
And also a package for code complete called **sublimecodeintel**.
There is not zf2 supported auto code complete.
For example, when I start writing

```
\Zend\Form\...
```

at each steps CTRL+Space does not give any subclasses of **Form**
or for example after this:

```
$testimonial = new \Application\Entity\Testimonial();
```

when I write this:

```
$testimonial->
```

CTRL+Space shows a list but there is no methods listed from **Testimonial** php class.

Please help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ZF2, really, this is just a question of how to configure an IDE with a 3rd party module. Please refer to the github of the `sublimecodeintel` author and open an issue there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might need to add the path to the ZF2 folder if they aren't in one of the project folders, or you could add a .codeintel/config file to your project root and add:

```
{
    "PHP": {
        "php": '/usr/bin/php',
        "phpExtraPaths": ['path/to/ZF2'],
        "phpConfigFile": 'php.ini'
    }
}
```

So make sure you have the paths set up correctly, and it should work.
Also SublimeCodeIntels default mappings for autocomple is:

- Linux: **<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>**
- Mac: **<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>**
- Windows: **<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text 2 is not an IDE and so does not have autocomplete. You could try installing the [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) package and see if that works for you.

Alternatively, consider [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/php/), [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/) or [Eclipse/PDT](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt) which are all IDEs that understand how to do auto complete with PHP.