# Name IDE function of auto-complete for functions, defines, etc in header files

Tags: autocomplete, editor

Qt Creator, Eclipse, and almost IDE's have an auto-complete for the functions that I had created in the headers files and I can navigate through the definitions of the functions.
First I want to know how that feature is called so I can search if it is possible to do the same with sublime text.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is called **code completion**. Keep in mind that to show up functions defined in other than the current file, you need to create a project (or whatever sublime calls this) so it can scan further files.

You might find this question usefull:
[Sublime Text 2 and ZF2 ... auto complete not works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373390/sublime-text-2-and-zf2-auto-complete-not-works)